# How to use bokeh select element to make sliders hide or invisible?

Tags: python, bokeh

[This sample is altered from the bokeh example, sliders can control the bars in the figure. (sliders.py)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WnBq.png)

This sample is altered from the bokeh example, sliders can control the bars in the figure. (sliders.py)
In my situation, there are more than 30 sliders on the left. It seems a little messy, so I am trying to use bokeh select element to connect sliders. The aim is the slider area will show only one slider when I select.

I read the document, and there are two ways to use:
One is disabled. If True, the widget will be greyed-out and not responsive to UI events. But it would not hide. Another is visible, but I got an attribute error:
AttributeError("unexpected attribute 'visible' to Slider, similar attributes are disabled")

Is it possible to make bokeh sliders hide or invisible? Or is there any other way to make sliders (more than 30) distinguish more clearly?

Here is the code which can run in Jupyter notebook

```
import bokeh.plotting.figure as bk_figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput
from bokeh.io import output_notebook # enables plot interface in J notebook
import numpy as np
# init bokeh        
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
    
    
output_notebook()
    
# Set up data
    
data = { 
    'line_x' : [1,2,3,4],
    'line_y' : [4,3,2,1],
    'bar_x':[1, 2, 3, 4],
    'bar_bottom':[1,1,1,1],
    'bar_top':[0.2, 2.5, 3.7, 4],
}
   
#bar_color
determine_top = data['bar_top']
determine_bottom = data['bar_bottom']
determine_color = []
for i in range(0,4):
    if (determine_top[i] > determine_bottom[i]): 
        determine_color.append('#B3DE69') #green
    else:
        determine_color.append('firebrick')
    i+=1
data['determine_colors'] = determine_color
    
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)
    
# Set up plot
plot = bk_figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=400, title="test",
                 tools="crosshair,pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom",
                 x_range=[0, 10], y_range=[-5, 5])
    
    plot.vbar(x='bar_x', width=0.5, top='bar_top',bottom='bar_bottom',
              source=source, color='determine_colors') 

# Set up widgets
select = Select(title="days_select:", 
                options=["d1_select", "d2_select", "d3_select", "d4_select"])

d1 = Slider(title="d1", value=0.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0, step=0.1)
d2 = Slider(title="d2", value=1.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0, step=0.1)
d3 = Slider(title="d3", value=0.0, start=0.0, end=2*np.pi)
d4 = Slider(title="d4", value=1.0, start=0.1, end=5.1, step=0.1)


# Set up callbacks
def update_data(attrname, old, new):
    # Get the current slider values
    d1_value = d1.value
    d2_value = d2.value
    d3_value = d3.value
    d4_value = d4.value

    ##select
    #if select.value == "d2_select":
    #   d3.disabled = True
    #   d4.visible = False
    
    
    # Generate the new curve
    new_data = {
        'line_x' : [1,2,3,4],
        'line_y' : [4,3,2,1],
        'bar_x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'bar_bottom':[d1_value, d2_value, d3_value, d4_value],
        'bar_top':[0.2, d1_value, d2_value, d3_value],
    }
    
    #bar_color
    determine_top = new_data['bar_top']
    determine_bottom = new_data['bar_bottom']
    determine_color = []
    for i in range(0,4):
        if (determine_top[i] > determine_bottom[i]): 
            determine_color.append('green') #green
        else:
            determine_color.append('red')
        i+=1
    new_data['determine_colors'] = determine_color

    source.data = new_data
    
for w in [select, d1, d2, d3, d4]:
    w.on_change('value', update_data)

# Set up layouts and add to document
layout = row(widgetbox(select, d1, d2, d3, d4), plot)

def modify_doc(doc):
    doc.add_root(row(layout, width=800))
    doc.title = "Sliders"

handler = FunctionHandler(modify_doc)
app = Application(handler)
show(app)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.